# ORACLE SQL query to get order by based on two columns null condtions

Tags: sql, oracle

i am struggling to get my result set out of a table please look at my requirement is as below..

Target table has ten columns , I would like display the result order by col a, col b both not nulls first then nulls last. I tried order by ASC nulls last but still showing nulls first.

Can anyone please help me on this.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, next time try to provide a 
[**SqlFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5368b/6) so we can understand the problem better and give you an answer 
much faster – Also please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
And [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing what you actually tried, it's hard to know what your issue is. I'm guessing that you specified `nulls last` once, expecting it to apply to the entire `order by` clause. You must specify it for each column you want sorted that way.

```
order by column1 asc nulls last, column2 asc nulls last
```